# query an array of objects and return a single object - mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I'm having some trouble searching an array I have in my model which currently contains dummy posts.

My posts array looks like this

```
posts: [
  {
    image: <filename>,
    comments: [],
    joined: <number>,
  }
]
```

The posts array atm holds about 10 objects. I need a way to query this array and return a single object. I already tried the answers given on other similar questions, but they all return the whole user which is not what I want.

I tried this:

```
model
  .find(
    { $match : { "posts.image": req.params.image } },
    { $unwind : "$posts" },
    { $match : { "posts.image": req.params.image } }
   )
```

This also returns the whole object including the password, username, etc. I also tried `$elemMatch`, and no luck.

I'm only expecting it to return one object (not multiple objects) since ill be querying the array with `req.params`.

Comment: Can you show the mongoose Schema instead of a posts array? It doesn't make much sense that you are using a mongoose query on a JSON Object.

Answer (score 0):

**Unsure**
Not entirely certain if this is what you are asking for, but a way to get a single property value of an array would be done this way

If I am misunderstood please clarify what you are after and I will amend my answer.

```js
var posts = [{
            image: "x.jpg",
            comments: [],
            joined: 12
           },
           {
            image: "x1.jpg",
            comments: [],
            joined: 121
           },
           {
            image: "ax.jpg",
            comments: [],
            joined: 2
           }
           ];

for (a = 0; a < posts.length; a++){
  console.log(posts[a].image);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP asks for help with a mongodb query.

Comment: im trying to return a single object from the posts array so if i wanted a image that was x.jpg then itll return the first object in the array and if its ax.jpg then itll be the third

Comment: Ok so your trying to find an indexof

Comment: Var intIndex = DataArray.indexOf("x.jpg"); if intIndex was 3 then DataArray[3] would return x.jpg. If the returned value is -1 then it wasnt found